# Reference to use index formula and name in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to ask, how about the code in writing VBA Excel like this.

```
Textbox1=Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(dataname, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SpinButton1.Value, indexdataname, 0), 3)
```

In simple formulas on sheets like

```
=INDEX(dataname,MATCH(number,indexdataname,0),3)
```

Comment: What is `indexdataname`? It is not defined. Same with `dataname`. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: dataname and indexdataname from define name. dataname A1: C15, indexdataname A1: A15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `indexdataname` and `dataname` are named ranges.

It would work with something like below:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define sheet name

Dim Dataname As Range
Set Dataname = ws.Range("dataname")

Dim IndexDataname As Range
Set IndexDataname = ws.Range("indexdataname")

Dim MatchedRow As Double
On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if no match is found
MatchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SpinButton1.Value, IndexDataname, 0)
On Error Goto 0 'always re-activate error reporting !!!

'test if something matched
If MatchedRow = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing matched", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Textbox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Dataname, MatchedRow, 9)
```

Comment: Your explanation is very perfect, complete with comments and very helpful for me who is still a layman studying excel. Once again, thank you